# in fundamental theorem of calculus, does the following reverse implication hold true?

Tags: integration

In FTC, define $G(t)=\int_a^xg(t)\mathrm{d}t$ on $[a,b]$, if $g$ is continuous, is $G$ continuous? I was not able to come up with a way to prove this implication, any help would be appreciated. Also, does this imply $G$ is differentiable?

Comment: $G$ is, in fact, continuously differentiable.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

By the FTC , $G$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $G'=g$ on $[a,b]$

Since $g$ is continuous, we have that $G \in C^1[a,b].$

Answer (score 0):

Not only that $G$ is continous, but also differentiable. When you use the FTC, you make the function "nicer" - so an integrable function become continous, and a continous function becomes differentiable.

Comment: could you put this into more rigorous mathematical language? thanks a ton.

Comment: You can find proofs to all of these theorms very easily, as they are some of the most basic and, well, _fundemental_ theorms in calculus.

Comment: do you have any idea in where i might find these theorems? thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus